# Launch multiple instances of external console application in QT and capture output?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am learning Qt and manged to use the following code from tutorials to launch external application and process output received from it :

```
void Dialog::on_startButton_clicked()
{

    QString program = "C:/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe";
    mTranscodingProcess = new QProcess(this);
    connect(mTranscodingProcess, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(processStarted()));
connect(mTranscodingProcess,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this,SLOT(readyReadStandardOutput()));
    connect(mTranscodingProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(encodingFinished()));


    QStringList arguments;
    QString input = "myfile_path_1";
    QString input2 = "myfile_path_2";

    arguments << "-y" << "-i" << input << "-i" << input2 << "-c" << "copy" << "output.avi" ;

    qDebug() << arguments;

    mTranscodingProcess->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    mTranscodingProcess->start(program, arguments);
}
```

This works as expected and I can capture and process output from `readyReadStandardOutput()` and `encodingFinished()` slots in my app.

Now my question is : How to launch additional jobs of the above and receive separate updates from each instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launching the additional jobs and receiving updates is easy enough; you just execute the code you posted above multiple times.

The only slightly tricky part (and I think the core of your question) is how to tell, when your readReadyStandardOutput() (or etc) slot is called, which of the several QProcess objects was the one that called it.

There are several ways to deal with that.  In no particular order:

- You could declare different slots for each QProcess object (e.g. readReadyStandardOutput1(), readReadyStandardOutput2(), etc) and connect each QProcess to different slots.  (Not really recommended unless you only have a very small number of QProcesses)
- You could create a separate ProcessLauncher class that derives from QObject, and create one ProcessLauncher object for each task you want to launch.  Have each ProcessLauncher object create its own QProcess object and connect the QProcess's signals to the ProcessLauncher's slots.  Since there is a 1:1 relationship between each ProcessLauncher and its QProcess, the ProcessLauncher would know that its slots were being called by its own QProcess and no other.
- You could use a [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html) object to help you differentiate the signals from each other.
- Or, if you don't mind subverting the object-oriented nature of the signals-and-slots paradigm, your slot methods can call [QObject::sender()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#sender) to find out which QProcess it is that emitted the signal, and alter their behavior based on sender()'s return value.

Comment: First one is of no use, as the intention here is to let user spawn ffmpeg processes on their will suitable to there computing resources. Out of the remaining which one is the easiest to implement, and can you provide an example as I am still new to Qt and object-oriented programming.

Comment: IMO the last one is the easiest to implement, just put this in your slot methods:   QProcess * sourceProcess = dynamic_cast<QProcess *>(sender());  ... et voila, you have a pointer to the QProcess that emitted the signal (or a NULL pointer if the signal was emitted by something else, although that shouldn't happen)

Comment: @Jeremy: Rather use `qobject_cast<QProcess*>(sender())`. The macro does a few extra checks to make sure that the `QObject` is a `QProcess`, otherwise returns 0. Before using `sourceProcess`, check if it is 0.

Comment: @RobbieE either qobject_cast() or dynamic_cast() will work in this case.  I agree that it's good to check the result to see if it's NULL, although if you're willing to guarantee that in your program only a QProcess will ever emit a signal that is connected to the slot, you could omit it (at the risk of crashing if you ever forgot your guarantee later on...)